# how to work with navigation properties in asp.net mvc web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net mvc 4 web api with EF code first model. I have a class with navigation property like like,

```
public class Branch
{
[Key]
public int Id{get; set;}
public List<book> books{get; set;}
}
```

and my book class is like,

```
public class book
{
[Key]
public int id{get; set;}
public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

Now i need to get list of branches so i write like,

```
public IQuerable<branch> GetBranches(int branchid)
{
  return context.school.where(m=>m.id==branchid).ToList().AsQuerable();
}
```

now i want to assign some data to book property in branch class so  did like,

```
context.school.ToList().ForEach(m=>m.books=GetBooks(branchid));
```

and now to get branch i have url like,

```
/api/branch/12
```

and is there any way to get particular book in a particular branch using url like

```
/api/branch/12/book/567
```

to return book number 567 in branch number 12. please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this kind of url to pass book to BranchController:

```
/api/branch/12?book=567
```

Or you can create new route for your url

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "BranchBooksApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/branch/{id}/book/{bookId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Branch" });
```

Both options will invoke method like

```
public book Get(int id, int bookId)
{
    //...
}
```

Also if you need to get book (it's not clear to me what you want - branch with single book, or just book from branch), then maybe `BooksController` is more appropriate place for this code.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the usage of OData and why they have introduced it? I thought OData was made to deal with navigation properties. Can you please explain?